# Why can I not trigger a Backbone view's function on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view with a `$(window).on("resize", function)` listener in the initialize function. I see others on SO doing this.

```
window.SidebarView = BaseView.extend({
    el: "#sidebar-container",
    template: HB.template("topics/sidebar"),

    events: {
        "click .sidebar-tab": "toggle_sidebar",
        "click .fade": "check_external_click",
        "click .sidebar-back": "sidebar_back_one_level"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        var self = this;

        $(window).on("resize", self.render);

        // blah blah more code
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.$el.html(this.template());

        // blah blah more code
    }
```

On window resize, I get an error at `this.$el.html(this.template());` in `render` saying undefined is not an object. I have tried changing `self.render` to `this.render`. Same issue. I'm sure I'm missing something tiny.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the scope is changing, when render() is triggered by your callback function it's passing in the window object as *this*, and window doesn't have an $el parameter.

You need to tell your function what context to run as. You can do this a variety of ways.. jQuery actually has a function specifically for this called proxy

```
window.SidebarView = BaseView.extend({
el: "#sidebar-container",
template: HB.template("topics/sidebar"),

events: {
    "click .sidebar-tab": "toggle_sidebar",
    "click .fade": "check_external_click",
    "click .sidebar-back": "sidebar_back_one_level"
},

initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    $(window).on("click", $.proxy(self.render, self));

    // blah blah more code
},

render: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.$el.html(this.template());

    // blah blah more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery changes the scope of functions called as events.

In your instance, this line :

```
$(window).on("resize", self.render);
```

Changes the scope in the `render` method to `window`. To get round this use an anonymous function as the callback and call the render method in its native scope.

```
initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    $(window).on("resize", function(event) {
        // Call render in the correct scope
        self.render();
    });

    // blah blah more code
},

render: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.$el.html(this.template());

    // blah blah more code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sooo... I ended up fixing it but doing

```
initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        self.resize_sidebar();
    });

    // blah blah more code
}
```

I've even done something similar before. I'm just having a slow day.